# Cant change speed for L293D

Tags: c++, arduino, project

I have no clue why I cant change `analogWrite(motor_enA, 255);`'s value from 255 to a smaller number, as the motor just stops working.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <Servo.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001";
Servo myservo; 

struct InputData  // define stuct
{
   int x;
   int y;
};

InputData data;


// Motor A connections
int motor_enA = 9;
int motor_in1 = 10;
int motor_in2 = 6;


int encoder1 = 2;
int encoder2 = 3;


volatile int counter = 0;
int angle = 0;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();


  // Set all the motor control pins to outputs
  pinMode(motor_enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_in2, OUTPUT);

  // Turn off motors - Initial state
  digitalWrite(motor_in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor_in2, LOW);
  analogWrite(motor_enA, 255);


  pinMode (encoder1, INPUT);
  pinMode (encoder2, INPUT);

  myservo.attach(5);
}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));
    myservo.write(data.x);  
    Serial.println(data.y);
    if (data.y > 15) {
      digitalWrite(motor_in1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motor_in2, LOW);
    }
    else if (data.y < -15) {
      digitalWrite(motor_in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor_in2, HIGH);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(motor_in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor_in2, LOW);
    }
  }
  
}
```

I have tried to change the number `255` to `254`, but then the motor doesn't turn.

Comment: I would guess, the pins are digital only (high/low).

Comment: is the RF24 part of the problem?

Comment: I don't think the RF24 is apart of the problem since the code that I am referring to has no connections with the RF24.

Comment: With online tutorials, it says that I can use numbers from 0-255 to define the speed. So no, I cannot use HIGH/LOW. Also note that it works perfectly fine with the value of 255.

Comment: Which online tutorials? Do you have a specific URL? If RF24 doesn't contribute, then reduce the example to the bare minimum. This will help to concentrate on the real point, and maybe it will solve the problem in the course.

Comment: Have you checked `data.y`? Maybe it is in the range `-15..15`. Then the code will stop the motor by setting LOW/LOW.

Comment: @GunvirDhesi *Please disable all code* regarding RF24 (comment it out) to be _sure_ there is no connection.  There _can_  be library internal connections that aren't visible externally, for example interrupts and i2c id.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you must start with a minimal sketch, then gradually add libraries and line of code. For example the SPI uses PIN 10 as Slave Select, and the Radio Library can interfere with the Timers of the Arduino, which can involve analogwrite.

Try this code : if it still doesn't work, then you have a hardware problem.

```
int motor_enA = 9;
int motor_in1 = 10;
int motor_in2 = 6;
int speed=255;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Set all the motor control pins to outputs
  pinMode(motor_enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_in2, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(motor_in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor_in2, LOW);
}

void loop() {
     delay(500);
     analogWrite(motor_enA, speed); 
     speed=speed-10;
     if (speed < 10) speed=255; 
}
```